# Rebuild fails where Clean/Build succeeds in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, dependencies, project-management

I've created two projects in a solution, a static library called vm and a console application called vmx.  I use the new approach of Framework and References to create the dependency of vm for vmx.  I also added x64 platforms to both projects.

Now, when I select Rebuild Solution, I get this output:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: vm, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  vm.c
1>  vm.vcxproj -> D:\Shared\Dynos\Build\Visual Studio 2010\Solutions\..\..\..\Lib\Win32\Debug\vm.lib
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: vmx, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>  main.c
2>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'D:\Shared\Dynos\Lib\Win32\Debug\vm.lib'
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

It as if vm.lib is deleted after being built before vmx is compiled.

If I select Clean Solution, then Build Solution, I get this output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: vm, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  vm.c
1>  vm.vcxproj -> D:\Shared\Dynos\Build\Visual Studio 2010\Solutions\..\..\..\Lib\Win32\Debug\vm.lib
2>------ Build started: Project: vmx, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>  main.c
2>  vmx.vcxproj -> D:\Shared\Dynos\Build\Visual Studio 2010\Solutions\..\..\..\Lib\Win32\Debug\vmx.exe
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Everything is OK.

Could someone explain to me what is happening here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.  The solution is to not to use the Frameworks and References feature in project settings and JUST use the old Project Dependencies system.  I removed my reference and clicked the checkbox in the Project Dependencies dialog box and it all works now.  Weird!

I huess Frameworks and References is just for C# projects and should be avoided for C++ ones.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem recently as well, and after much head banging, I realized that **the output directory was the same** on several of the projects. So project A would get rebuilt fine, however when project B was "rebuilt" it would clean out the output directory including projectA's .lib and .dll files, and subsequent project rebuilds would fail.

Our fix for the moment for our auto build was to do a clean, then a build on the solution, instead of doing rebuild or clean/rebuild. Obviously the alternative would be to change the projects to each have their own output directory.

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the intermediate directory that has been cleaned before the next project got built. This was really confusing, as I didn't knew what exactly will be separated into that directory and my solution and project files are all in the directory.

If you have the solution file *.sln and the referenced project files *.vcxproj all in one directory, then add `$(TargetName)\` to the value of `Project Properties > Configuration Properties > General > Intermediate Directory` or replace it with `$(Configuration)\Int\$(ProjectName)\`.

This is needed for me, as I use the project in other solutions, too.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered similar problems. Certain versions of Visual Studio have this problem (see [reference](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/rebuild-fails-but-build-works/245880)). I was using `Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.2.6`, and switched to different versions (`Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.18` and `Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 RC (64-bit) Version 17.0.0 RC2`), which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1)Might be some **dependency** issue

OR

> 2)Some old intermediate files might be remaining during rebuild which
>   get deleted during clean & are replaced by new, correct ones during fresh build.

Comment: I don't think it's a dependency issue since there is only one dependency and I set that up.  It's just that the rebuild is failing, but clean/build is ok.  It's weird.  This is a brand new project set up in a new folder.

Comment: I am getting the same problem regardless of whether a 64-bit build configuration exists or not.  I delete the output files and rebuild - it fails, I delete the output files and build - works!  I have no idea why.